# Solution verification for functional dependency using armstrong axioms

Tags: candidate-key

I have the following functional dependencies which includes all attributes of the relation:

{AB -> C, BC -> AD, D -> E, CF -> B}

CF supposedly is a candidate key. The task is: Show that CF is a candidate key given the functional dependencies listed

ACF -> AB (Augmentation)

AB  -> C  (Follows directly form functional dependencies)

BC  -> BAD (Augmentation)

BC  -> D (Decomposition)

D   -> E (Follows directly from functional dependencies)

This came up as part of an algorithm, which has no name in my script. In line 10 the candidate key {CF} was discovered and I wanted to verify that it is indeed a candidate key.

1. LEFT = {F}
2. NOWHERE = {}
3. MIXED = {ABCD}
4. RIGHT = {E}
5. 2^MIXED = {{}, {A}, {B}, {C}, {D},
   {AB}, {AC}, {AD}, {BC}, {BD}, {CD},
   {ABC}, {ABD}, {ACD}, {BCD}, {ABCD}}
6. LEFT ∪ NOWHERE = {F}
7. {F}G+ (Closure) = {F}
   2^MIXED = {{A}, {B}, {C}, {D},
   {AB}, {AC}, {AD}, {BC}, {BD}, {CD},
   {ABC}, {ABD}, {ACD}, {BCD}, {ABCD}}
8. {AF}G+ = {AF}
   2^MIXED = {{B}, {C}, {D},
   {AB}, {AC}, {AD}, {BC}, {BD}, {CD},
   {ABC}, {ABD}, {ACD}, {BCD}, {ABCD}}
9. {BF}G+ = {BF}
   2 MIXED = {{C}, {D},
   {AB}, {AC}, {AD}, {BC}, {BD}, {CD},
   {ABC}, {ABD}, {ACD}, {BCD}, {ABCD}}
10. {CF}G+ = {CFBADE} Candidate key!
    2 MIXED = {{D},
    {AB}, {AD}, {BD},
    {ABD}}
11. {DF}G+ = {DFE}
    2 MIXED = {{AB}, {AD}, {BD},
    {ABD}}
12. {ABF}G+ = {ABFCDE} Candidate key!
    2 MIXED = {{AD}, {BD}}
13. {ADF}G+ = {ADFE}
    2 MIXED = {{BD}}
14. {BDF}G+ = {BDFE}
    2 MIXED = {}

I also have no idea why the author choose the description 2^mixed for the combinations of all the attributes

Comment: This is not clear. What are you trying to do? Do you seek a certain FD set? Do you seek to show that the alleged CK is a CK? If so that reasoning presentation doesn't connect your application of the axioms to the definition of CK. Also: You don't explain what each line is doing in that list. You don't say how lines with rules arise from the rule. Use enough words to be clear, don't just put some stuff on the page. PS For implication both -> & => get used although => is properly for inference. For FDs -> is used & not =>. PS Two spaces at line end gives a line break, see the edit help.

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: You need to give the algorithm including what it expects as input & gives as output & where you got it. Presumably you have a textbook, please give the name & edition. Also you continue to not explain what this has to do with the question you are answering, you still just dump unexplained fragments on the page. PS You can verify that a set is a CK by either applying an appropriate algorithm or showing that the definition is satisfied.

Comment: The algorithm finds all the candidate keys. I have no textbook unfortunately only a script which hardly explains anything..The algorithm discovered a candidate key in line 10. I wanted to verify that it is indeed a candidate key given the functional dependencies. I don't have any additional information.